# Java threading countdown a number

Tags: java, multithreading

This java application will start three threads and countdown a number. once counter reaches zero, the thread will finish and exit. unfortunately, the counter will bypass the zero check. how to fix it ?

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class ThreadTest {
    volatile Long totalMsg = 100L;
    final Lock maxLimitLock = new ReentrantLock();

    public void start() {
        int threadNumber = 3;
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadNumber);
        for (int i = 0; i < threadNumber; i++) {
            executor.submit(new ThreadTest.ConsumerThread(i));
        }      
    }
    class ConsumerThread implements Runnable {
        private int threadNumber;
        public ConsumerThread(int threadNumber) {
            this.threadNumber = threadNumber;
        }
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    maxLimitLock.lock();
                    totalMsg--;
                    System.out.println(totalMsg + " left");
                    if (totalMsg == 0) {
                        System.out.println("finished all of " + totalMsg);
                        break;
                    }
                } finally {
                    maxLimitLock.unlock();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("thread " + this.threadNumber + " finished");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ThreadTest reader = new ThreadTest();
        reader.start();
    }
}
```

thanks.

Comment: it would be esyer to change the while condition to totalMsg > 0 and than execute what you have in the if outside the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is here

```
totalMsg--;
...
if (totalMsg == 0) {
```

Your code always decrement your counter such that only one thread can be released, subsequent threads will have a counter < 0 so they will never be released, so you should replace it with

```
if (totalMsg <= 0) {
```

or

```
if (totalMsg > 0) {
    totalMsg--;
    System.out.println(totalMsg + " left");
} else {
    System.out.println("finished all of " + totalMsg);
    break;
}
```

**NB:** Consider using an `AtomicLong` for your counter.